# Duplicating Entities with @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two Entities: Meal and Product. Each Meal has a couple of products, and each Product can exist in each meal, so the relation is @ManyToMany, where Meal is a parent.

I would like to save Meal with Products, but the problem is that products are duplicating in DB.

How to archive a case where if the Product exists in DB, do not save it, but just wire with existing?

(Application parse products from external API (Nutritionix), collecting them together, and then is saving separately products, and Meal as a Parent with calculated data)

I tried to insert
`if(!productService.ifExists(food.getFoodName())) productService.save(food);`
into saving function and get rid of cascadeType, but when product already exists I'm getting an error:

`org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:`

```
@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "foodList")
private Set<Meal> meals = new HashSet<>();

@Column(unique = false, nullable = false)
private String foodName;
...}
```

...

```
@Entity
public class Meal {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(cascade ={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<Product> foodList = new HashSet<>();

@NaturalId
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String mealName;
...}
```

...

```
    public Meal saveMeal(List<Food> foodList, String mealName){

    Meal newMeal = new Meal();
    newMeal.setMealName(mealName);

    List<Product> productList = parseFoodToProduct(foodList);

    productList.stream().forEach(y -> newMeal.getFoodList().add(y));

    for(Product food : productList) {
        newMeal.setNfCalories(newMeal.getNfCalories() + food.getNfCalories());
        newMeal.setNfCholesterol(newMeal.getNfCholesterol() + food.getNfCholesterol());
        newMeal.setNfDietaryFiber(newMeal.getNfDietaryFiber() + food.getNfDietaryFiber());
        newMeal.setNfP(newMeal.getNfP() + food.getNfP());
        newMeal.setNfPotassium(newMeal.getNfPotassium() + food.getNfPotassium());
        newMeal.setNfProtein(newMeal.getNfProtein() + food.getNfProtein());
        newMeal.setNfSaturatedFat(newMeal.getNfSaturatedFat() + food.getNfSaturatedFat());
        newMeal.setNfSodium(newMeal.getNfSodium() + food.getNfSodium());
        newMeal.setNfSugars(newMeal.getNfSugars() + food.getNfSugars());
        newMeal.setNfTotalCarbohydrate(newMeal.getNfTotalCarbohydrate() + food.getNfTotalCarbohydrate());
        newMeal.setNfTotalFat(newMeal.getNfTotalFat() + food.getNfTotalFat());
        newMeal.setServingWeightGrams(newMeal.getServingWeightGrams() + food.getServingWeightGrams());
        
    }

    return mealService.save(newMeal);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, maybe call the ingredients `Ingredient`s and not `Product`s.

Second, the problem probably lies in the code of method `parseFoodToProduct(foodList);` that we cannot see, in connection with the directive

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(cascade ={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<Product> foodList = new HashSet<>();
```

If you create new `Product`s (`xxx = new Product(...)`) in `parseFoodToProduct(foodList);`, instead of loading them from the database, this surely will backfire.

Leave out the `CascadeType`, and always create/retrieve/update/store the `Product`s on their own so they're completely independent of where they are used/referenced.

Comment: parseFoodToProduct(foodList); is prasing products from external API (Nutritionix), then saveMeal(List<Food> foodList, String mealName) is collecting them together, calculating macro ingredients and then is saving separately products, and meal as a Parent with calculated data.

Comment: Thanks, that works well. But now I need to find a way to distinguish products with different quantities.  All schema to rewrite.. ;)

Comment: Instead of `private Set<Product> foodList = new HashSet<>();` you could use a `private Map<Product,Double> foodList = new HashMap<>();` where the `Double` defines the exact amount if the ingredient. Unless, of course, you want to add cooking times and separate descriptions to each `Product` used in `Meal`. Then I suggest you create a class `IngredientUsage` that has all these properties, along with the `Product` and quantity information. And then in meal you do: `private Set<IngredientUsage> foodList = new HashSet<>();`. This way you have Meal <> IngredientUsage <> Product and max flexibility.